# Normalizing an array so the summation of the array is equal to the size of the array

Tags: statistics

I am trying to normalize the array, so that the sum of their elements is equal to the size of the array. If $\alpha_i$ are the elements of the array of size $C$, I want to normalize the array, so the property below holds.

[image: Image is showing summation of alpha from variable i=1 to i=C is equal to C]

Is it possible to normalize the array as described above? If yes, how can I approach the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First get the original sum of the array, call that $A$ and divide each array entry by $A.$ At this point array sum is $1.$ Second multiply each of the new array's  elements by your desired sum $C.$ After both steps the array sum will be $C.$ You can check this yourself.

Note this method won't work if the original array sum is zero. [Can't divide by zero.]